# Reporting Services SQL Server 2005 File Share Error

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-7, reporting-services

I have a problem with Reporting Services, on an XP box, trying to save subscription reports onto a Windows 7 box over the network. No matter the permissions or accounts used by reporting services it always comes back with "A logon error occurred when attempting to access the file share. The user account or password is not valid."

Since this is saving reports over the network and both admin accounts and open network/file permissions to everyone were both tried so I'm left wondering if this is an issue with Reporting Services 2005 has troubles with Windows 7 over the network.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using an account with identical names and passwords on both the reporter server and destination server solved the problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is this the actual solution? I believe you must have got a proper solution now. Please share.